# Converting a schema to a second normal form

Tags: database, database-design

Consider a basic table schema:

> StudentID, Student Name,  Department, courseCode, Course Name, year-Semester, Grade

How can I convert it to **second normal form** by identifying functional dependencies?

Comment: Read some books of database. Then you will definitely can do this task by your own.

Comment: You identify functional dependencies by knowing the business rules you need to model in the database or by finding them out (through talking to analysts, users and other stakeholders). Inventing business rules based only on a list of attribute names is not much more than guess work and word games. Someone else's guess is no better than yours.

Answer (score 5):

I use a mnemonic device for the first three normal form. I use the word RePeaT ignoring the vowels. First is no Repeating groups or multivalued fields, second no Partial dependence on primary key and finally no Transitory dependence.

In your case it looks like a 1NF problem rather than 2NF. A 2NF means partial dependence and looking at your table there is no composite primary key i.e primary keys having more than 1 field therefore there is no possibility of partial dependence. So for 1NF there are 2 possibilities one has repeated groups the other one is multi- valued fields. So, example of 1NF with repeating groups is [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/first-normal-form.htm) and multi-valued example is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

It would be better if you have the actual records/rows of your table and ask the question: are there any repeating groups or are there any multivalued fields? From there you can begin answering your problem by using the examples I provided above.

**Based on your new information**:

You have:

```
 Table : Student
 Fields : StudentID, Student Name, Department

 Table : Course
 Fields : CourseCode, Course Name, Year, Semester

 Table: TableGrade
 Fields : StudentID, CourseID, Grade
```

And If we follow what you want which is TableGrade with no Course Taken (or Course Offered as you will see later on)then we need to either add one more field in your Course table to match your TableGrade table or change one field of your TableGrade:

If you want to change Course table only it would be like this:

```
Table: Course
Fields: CourseID, CourseCode, Course Name, Year, Semester
```

If you want to change TableGrade only it would be like this:

```
Table: TableGrade
Fields: StudentID, CourseCode, Grade
```

However, if you look at **Course** table there is a problem.
 Let's say you have the original one:

```
CourseCode, Course Name, Year, Semester
```

If you look at this carefully Course Name will come on repeating unnecessarily
 which is actually a violation 1NF, that is, no repeating groups. In this
 case CourseCode and Course Name repeats unnecessarily.

And if you use also observe the proposed changes that I mentioned it will still have a problem:

```
CourseID, CourseCode, Course Name, Year, Semester
```

In this case it violates the 3NF which says no Transient Dependence. In this case
 Course Name is dependent on CourseCode and not on CourseID which is the primary key.

Another thing is we know that Courses has sections, so you would have at least

```
 CourseCode, Course Name, Section, Year, Semester
```

So, that's why it make  more sense to have a Courses Taken or actually more
appropriately Course Offered and then add another Table name Courses as reference Table.

So, the new schema would be like:

```
 Table : Student
 Fields : StudentID, Student Name, Department

 Table : CoursesOffered
 Fields : CourseID, CourseCode, Section, Year, Semester

 Table: Courses
 Fields : CourseCode, Course Name

 Table: TableGrade
 Fields : StudentID, CourseID, Grade
```

Do this one makes sense to you?

Comment: As far as I understand, to fit with 1NF, I need to separate the year semester first. It then becomes; table student (StudentID, Student Name, Department, courseCode, Course Name, year, Semester, Grade). For the 2NF each non key attribute should depend on the key, therefore I separate the table into three different tables as: table student (StudentID, Student Name, Department), table course(courseCode, Course Name, year,Semester) and having a third table, i.e. table grade (Student ID, Course ID, Grade), any comments?

Comment: I think you're almost there. Course table probably should have only CourseCode, CourseName and then you have another table CourseTaken that has the following fields CourseCode, StudentID, Year, Semester (or Year-Semester).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually, I have a new question regarding your comment. Do we really need a course taken table, why grade table is not enough? I thought grade table is useful enough to merge the course and the student table.

Comment: Thanks for all the details, it is extremely helpful for me to have such a discussion!

What I have understand is that you have introduced the CourseID variable to solve the multiple dependency problem? (I do not have it on the preliminary form)

So the primary keys would be: StudentID for student table, course code course name (both) for course table, course id for coursesOffered table, and student id and course id would be the foreign keys in table grade. So the key(s) should present the functional dependencies?

Comment: You have your CourseID in your comment above (look at the 3rd comment). But anyway yes you are right, this keys and table(s) that we introduced will normalize the relations (tables) and thus having the right functional dependencies.